# Batch resizing of textures

Tags: textures, editors

I have a large number of png files that I need resize so the sides are in powers of 2 without stretching the images in those files. Basically add/remove white-space so the image is in the upper left corner of the image and it is sized appropriately. Because of the large number of files I would rather not edit them individually if at all possible.

Comment: You probably could use imagemagick. Here is info on how to scale and pad: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#square
Either mix that with some shell magic or use mogrify (imagemagicks tool for multiple images) to batch process.

Comment: @JonasBeck I don't think that's what I'm looking for. It seems like that tool assumes I already know what size I want the final image to be and makes the height and width the same. Essentially I need to remove any white-space then round up to the nearest power of 2 then add white-space back in. Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: Personally, I'd try to come up with a script written in Python with PIL, the image library. But that's just me.

Comment: @cHorse Well it would be possible with those tools, but you'd have to use some rather obscure syntax. Vaillancourt is probably right - possible or not, you'd have an easier time writing something in python.